# CodeBlocks: how to AUTOMATICALLY move method implementation from header to source?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

**Short problem description:**

I am building software using CodeBlocks IDE. Initially I have all the code inside one file, but when the project grows, I want to split it into multiple files. Is it possible in CodeBlocks to do that automatically?

**Longer problem explanation:**

Suppose my c++ header file looks like this:

```
 #ifndef MY_CLASS_H
 #define MY_CLASS_H

 #include "file_required_for_method_implementation.h"
 #include "other_unrelated_file.h"

 class MyClass {
     void Method() {
         // Some code here
     }

     void Unrelated();
 } 


 #end_if // MY_CLASS_H
```

I want to re-factor the code and move the `Method()` implementation to the .cc file.

My new header file should look like this:

```
#ifndef MY_CLASS_H
#define MY_CLASS_H

// Note the missing #include directive: it is now moved to the cc file.
#include "other_unrelated_file.h"

class MyClass {
    void Method();

    void Unrelated();
}

#end_if // MY_CLASS_H
```

Hence, my main question is:

**Is it possible in CodeBlocks to re-factor the files automatically with a few mouse button clicks, without having to manually copy paste the code and all relevant parts** (especially the `#include` directives)? An alternative shell command would also satisfy me.

Comment: Right about now you really wish you were using Visual Studio with [Visual Assist](http://wholetomato.com/)...

Comment: Isn't `Visual Studio` Microsoft specific? What if I am using Linux OS?